# How to get translucent background for an Android activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I want a translucent background for my activity but the content of the activity like button and images should be visible normally.

I am using minSdkVersion 17 and my activity extends AppCompatActivity.

What kind of styling feature I should use to achieve my goal?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can change background of activity as -

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:background="#27ffffff"/>
```